# Call external lib in flutter

Tags: flutter, desktop

I would like to know if it is possible to use an external library written in another language for example (C ++, Go Lang, Rust) in a desktop application (windows, linux) developed in flutter

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if more languages are possible to use. But you can use native C libraries (and JavaScript for Dart Web).

Have a look at:

https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop

https://dart.dev/web/js-interop